Is there a CSS only way to target the last nested element by className?


.parent .child:last-child {
  color: red;
}
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  text
    <div class="child">
      text
      <div class="child">text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



I would only like the text of the last nested child to have a font-color of red. is this acheivable with CSS only?

You can use the :not() selector in combination with :has() to dynamically target the innermost .child div:


.child:not(:has(.child)) {
  color: red;
}
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  text
    <div class="child">
      text
      <div class="child">text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




very clever. thanks.

the selector would something like a div with class child that has not a child with class child : .child:not(:has(.child))


.child:not(:has(.child)) {
  color: red;
}
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    text
    <div class="child">
      text
      <div class="child">text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




You can do as suggested above, or you can type once an inline CSS on the selector that you want for example


<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    text
    <div class="child">
      text
      <div class="child" style="color: red;">text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



